# Making a transaction-like behaviour when interacting with multiple systems

Tags: c#, design-patterns, sequence, monads

**Disclaimer**
In the following post:
`action`= `Action`/`Func`

I have a long method that does multiple actions(s).Each action is wrapped in a `try-catch`.If the specific action fails , in the `catch` i must perform a `clear` action for all previous ones and the current one.
I do not know a way to stop duplicating code in the `catch` and aggregate them using a design pattern or something.

**What i have currently**

```
public void LongMethod()
{
   try
   {
      try
      {
        action1();
      }catch(Exception ex)
      {
        ClearAction1();
      }
      try{
        action2();
      }catch(Exception ex){
         Clearaction1();
         Clearaction2();
      }
      try
      {
         action3();

      }
      catch(Exception ex)
      {
         Clearaction1();
         Clearaction2();
         Clearaction3();
      }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
       //how should i aggregate the action clearance here
   }

}
```

In the above method i do not want to write in all catch blocks all the `clear` actions up until that point.
I would like for each successful action to set something like a checkpoint , and then when that fails , check the `state` and perform all required clearing up until that point.

**What i would like**

```
public void LongMethod()
{
   try
   {
      int checkpoint=0;
      action1();
      checkpoint=1;
      action2();
      checkpoint=2;
      action3();
      checkpoint=3; 
      action4();   //fails here
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {   
        switch(checkpoint)
        {
            3//does Clearaction1()+Clearaction2()+Clearaction3()+Clearaction4();
        }
    }
}
```

I was thinking if there is something like a design pattern to wrap each of these `actions` which might have different return types and pipeline them.Whichever `actionN` fails it triggers `Clearaction1()`...`ClearactionN()` where N is the `Action` that did fail.

**P.S** It might be something like a `monad`.

`m a ->(a->m b) -> m b` ->  `(m b -> (b -> m c) -> m c)` -> `(m c -> ( c -> m d) -> m d)` 
where `a` ,`b`,`c`,`d` are types the difference being that i need to aggregate all failure treatment.

**Update**

After answers on this forum i felt i needed to do some additions:

This is an endpoint inside a `ASP NET Controller`.I retrieve data from multiple systems and with the fetched data i am setting other systems.
What i want to this to look like is like a distributed system transaction:

**Fetch Input Systems** 
 `[A,B]`
**To Output Systems** 
`[X,Y]`

**Example of sequence**

- fetch data from `A`
- set data on `X` (using `A` data)  (and get response `Z`)
- fetch data from `B`
- set data on `Y` (using data fetched from  `B` and `Z`)

**Secenario**
Now lets say the the `fetch data from B` fails i want to:
- clear data from `X` only

I do not want to attempt to clear data on `Y` since it would produce irrevocable damage.

I care only about the `I/O` actions that `set` data.

Comment: An `Action` has always a return of type `void`. Otherwise it would be a `Func`. I was thinking about doing something that _is_ actually transactional. But that'll depend on what those `Action`s do. Do you _have_ a state object or something alike? Do the `Action`s have sideeffects outside mutating that state?

Comment: Forgive me i named them improperly you are right.By `action`(s) i meant both `Func` and `Action`.Some of them do have return types others don't.Some of them  depend on each other.A sequence could be `Func >> Action >> Func >> Action`. The methods do have side-effects.

Comment: Perhaps not relevant to your question, but have you considered what will happen if your process terminates in the middle of this "transaction"?

Comment: I know its not rlly ok but they all need to happen so that is why currently i had a big `catch` and i was running all `clear actions` , which had logic inside them that would check if execution was needed or not.

Comment: By "depend on each other" you mean for example Action2 must not be called without calling Action1 before?

Comment: Yes.Some  `actions`(`Func` or `Action`) depend on the return the previous (`Func`'s), while others don't but need to be executed before (business logic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your code is not very-very performance/allocation critical you can just create a list of "reverse actions" and boolean variable to track success:

```
public void LongMethod()
{
   var reverseActions = new List<Action>();
   var success = false;
   try
   {
      int checkpoint=0;
      Action1();
      reverseActions.Add(ClearAction1);
      Action2();
      reverseActions.Add(ClearAction2);
      ...
      success = true;
   }
   finally // or can be catch if you can/want to handle/swallow exception
   {   
         if(!success)
         {
            foreach(var a in reverseActions)
            {
             a();
            }
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you could simply build a list of pairs of actions and the corresponding compensating action. Then iterate from 1 to N, applying each action. If an exception is caught in step I, iterate backwards from I to 1 through the list of compensating actions.

Also, it is possible to use monads for compensation, e.g. the [cats-saga](https://github.com/VladKopanev/cats-saga/blob/master/README.md) library for Scala cats

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to have one state object, that takes all "side-effects", you can do something like this:

```
public State LongMethod( State originalState ) // assuming, `State` is your state object type
{
    //                     vv Copy-CTOR == "Begin Transaction"
    State localState = new State(originalState); 
    try{
       // mutate _the local copy_
       action1(localState);
       var intermediateResult = func2(localState);
       action3(localState, intermediateResult);
       // ...
       return localState; // return mutated state == "Commit"
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // return unchanged state == "Rollback"
        return originalState;
    }
}
```

Why did I bother to add this after a different answer has already been accepted?

I wanted to present this alternative, regarding Martin's comment:

> Perhaps not relevant to your question, but have you considered what will happen if your process terminates in the middle of this "transaction"?

If the process terminates amidst above code, you have a consistent state: the unchanged one.

*Downside* is: It really only works if you *can* isolate a state and do not depend on events triggered in the process.

To make it more clear: If in the process, let's say `action5` does a `HTTP PUT` to API XYZ, then this solution is not enough because you would have to actively reverse that `PUT`.

Comment: That is what i meant at the end by enclosing all these actions in `monads`.Thus the result of an action can be an obiect that could be in one of two states: Exception/Result (Maybe Result). So i could have a class : `class Monad<T>{ Exception ex; T result;}`

Comment: By a state object with all side effects , you mean an object that can trigger all `I/O` calls etc right ? I might have that , and yes your implementation was actually what i wanted to apply computations on an object that can at each step fail.My question would be , where would you place the `ClearAction` logic for each computation ? I do not want to just throw an exception. The exception handling also would also trigger side effects.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian In this case, the "state object" is merely a "database", a collection of properties, if you will. It saves data as it is at a specific point in time during computations. The point of above solution is: You don't need "ClearAction"s, because you simply discard all changes at once in case of an error.  _But_ as already stated in the answer: This can only work if you do not change state somewhere else, that has to be changed back, too.

Comment: What do you mean by somewhere else? To fledge more context : this is a method inside a `ASP NET Web API` controller. This is an initialization method , where i am trying to fetch data  (`I/O` calls) from some systems (`A`,`B`) and set other data to some other systems  (`X`,`Y`). A sequence could be `get A -> set X , get B -> set Y `. However i do care about where the  sequence has reached. I do not want attempt to clear the data from systems that have not been querried yet. Example : `get A -> set X , get B` fails at `get B`.In this case i do not want to try to clear `Y`.

Comment: OK, in that case, you cannot use it. "Somewhere else" would mean systems x and y. Read-Only IO wouldn't matter. But setting something in system x is an external state change. So, if you need to reverse that in case of an error, then this solution is not enough.

Comment: In my case  `X` and `Y` could be `2` databases

Comment: Still kinda hard to do. If it were only 1 db , I'd say use its transaction functionality. But with two, it's tricky. if you have db A and B and on both you start transactions, then do your mutations, then you commit Transaction(A), then commit Transaction(B) but it fails to commit ... you cannot rollback A so easily, once the transaction is committed ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213841/discussion-between-bercovici-adrian-and-fildor).